# Modal verbs. Could+simple infinitive or could+perfect infinitive?

Tags: modal-verbs

Studying the use of the modal verb "can" I was confronted with a problem whether I have to use could+simple infinitive or could+perfect infinitive in this case:
1) "Nobody could make greater impression on me that you did."
2) "Nobody could have made greater impression on me that you did."
Can I use both variants or there's a difference in meaning?

Comment: The difference between *They could **make** an impression* and *They could **have made** an impression* is simply that in the former (present tense) case ***it's still possible***.

Comment: Both are incorrect because the idiom is _make **an** impression_ and the articles are omitted. That's a glaring error that makes all the other errors almost invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody could make a greater impression on me than you did.

This could be expanded: Nobody could make a greater impression on me either now or in the future than you did at that time.

Nobody could have made a greater impression on me than you did.

This could be expanded: Nobody could have made a greater impression on me at that time than you did at that time.